# Get the total count of id which is visible

Tags: jquery, visibility

I am working on a travel booking website. First I will retrieve all the data from webservice and display in page as table. Then on clicking select everything will be hidden and only the selected table will remain in page. Now let me ask the question.

In that table I have dynamic rows..
The only hope I have is `ID-{llalc1,llalc2,....}` which is created dynamically..
Now I want to find the count of llalc without giving `1,2,3..`

All I have is

```
var counts = $("input[id*='llalc']").filter(function () {
    return this.style.display !== "none";
}).length;
```

But it returns count as 372..(It includes all invisible elements too)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [**:visible** visible-selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fe9Hn/1/)

```
var counts = $("input[id*='llalc']:visible").length;
```

or

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fe9Hn/)

```
var counts = $("input[id*='llalc']").filter(':visible').length;
```

Comment: Re-think on your second snippet.

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer Yes because boolean value does not have a length property.

Comment: So what i need to do in this case..from the above code,it returns undefined for first and 0 for second..

Comment: Nope it returns either 346 or 0..The thing is i am getting value from an hidden element..<input type="hidden">

Comment: Thanks for all..I did a minor change and got the expected output..the change is just assigned id for <b></b> and used your code..It works..

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to do

```
  var Divcount = $("input[id*='llalc']:visible").length
```